# Pass TreeViewItem Tag to Event Handler c#

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Ok, Below is my code so far i am attempting to add a menu to a Custom File Browser. Right now I am working on a new folder button but want to add more items to the menu eventually. My question is how to fist pass the tag from the item to the Menu_MouseLeftClick Event Handler. Thanks in advance for help I am new thanks in advance.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace TreeViewWithMenu
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        //Create Objects and Handlers
        InitializeComponent();
        PopTree();
        SetMenu();
        this.treeView.MouseRightButtonDown += TreeView_MouseRightButtonDown;
        this.menu.MouseLeftButtonDown += Menu_MouseLeftButtonDown;

    }

    private void TreeView_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    { 
        //Make Folder Visable
        this.menu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void SetMenu()
    {
        //Set Menu for new Folder
        MenuItem MeItem = new MenuItem();
        MeItem.Header = "New Folder";
        MeItem.Tag = "New Folder";
        menu.Items.Add(MeItem);
        menu.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    }

    private void Menu_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create New FOlder
        Directory.CreateDirectory("");
    }



    internal void PopTree()
    {
        //Populate Tree
        List<string> CleanDirs = new List<string>();

        string [] Dirs =  Directory.GetDirectories(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));

        string temp;
        foreach (string dir in Dirs)
        { temp = SplitPath(dir); CleanDirs.Add(temp.ToUpper()); }

        foreach(var ShowIn in CleanDirs)
        {
            TreeViewItem TreeViewDirectory = new TreeViewItem();
            TreeViewDirectory.Tag = ShowIn;
            TreeViewDirectory.Header = ShowIn;
            TreeViewDirectory.Focusable = true;
            this.treeView.Items.Add(TreeViewDirectory);

        }

    }

    private string SplitPath(string path)
    {
        string[] temp = path.Split('\\');

        return temp[temp.Length - 1];
    }
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SelectedItem` property to access the currently selected item from the `TreeView`, which should be the same item you right-clicked on.

```
private void TreeView_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView.SelectedItem == null)
        return;

    var selectedTag = ((TreeViewItem)treeView.SelectedItem).Tag;

    // do something with the tag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add control (TreeViewItem) manually.
Use Collection as view model
Bind to the collection from the treeView ItemsSource property.
Use DataTemplate to bind to the relavent properties on the view model to the dependency properties on the TreeViewItem control.

All the pluming should be from the Xaml file